# Display most frequent value in Tableau per location

Tags: dataset, location, tableau-api, calculated-field

I am trying to show the most frequent employee number per location.

For an example, if 10 is the most frequent number in my dataset relating to New York, I would like "10" to show up as the value next to New York. I have several other locations so is this possible?

I have tried to create a calculated field but it did not work for me.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are your numbers all integers?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Yes, they are.

Comment: Then @AnilGoyal’s solution or a similar variant is likely your best initial approach. If you have very large datasets and see a performance issue, you could look into using “analytic or windowing” queries via custom SQL, but I’d only go there if needed. (The reason I asked whether the field was an integer is that using a floating point field as a dimension, aka group by field in SQL, is not always reliable”

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Yes, AnilGoyal's solution worked for me. Thank you for your insight on this as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most frequent value i.e. `MODE` is calculated for a dimension normally.  In tableau mode is also calculated for a dimension.  However, for your use case, you may do a workaround like this-

For the following workaround I have created a sample data like this

[image]

**Step-1** Create a calculated field say `CF1` with the following calculation

```
{ FIXED [City] : Max ({FIXED [City], [Measure]: COUNT([Measure])})}
=
{FIXED [City], [Measure] : COUNT([Measure])}
```

**Step-2** Convert the Measure into dimension (by right clicking it).  If you require it as a measure for some future aggregation (create a copy of this field)

**Step-3** Add `city` and `measure` on rows shelf.

**Step-4** create a filter on `CF1`. (Now when `TRUE` values are filtered only the most frequent value in Measure for each city will only be displayed.  The following screenshots will help in explaining the things.

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: This worked! I missed some of the calculation so that is why it did not work for me before. Thank you so much for your quick solution. I truly appreciate it.

Happy Holidays to you & yours :)

Comment: Yes, for sure. Just upvoted your answer. Thank you again :)

Comment: What if you have two measures with similar count?